# Padding style responds when I uncheck, then re check styling box in console

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set some light padding-left and padding-right  in my table, but it only seems to respond when I am messing around with it in the editor. When I first load the page, the `Computed` tab in the Chrome console area seems to acknowledge there's padding around my `td` but does not display it, and slams the data right up against its border, even allowing the last data character to appear "underneath" its own border if the column header isn't wider than the cell content (displayed in #1 below).

However when I uncheck the style css element to disable it, then re-check it, the padding style takes and displays as intended. Any idea what's happening?

**1. Initial load**
[image: Before unchecking]

**2. After-unchecking any of the padding style boxes**

[image: after un-checking]
**3. After-rechecking the boxes, displays table cells as desired**
[image: after re-checking]

I am noticing that in the Chrome console displayed style tab for the CSS, that I am competing with one of the Bootstrap CSS style rules (the one pictured as `td, th`). But both rules are present and in full (not greyed out) on the table's initial load.

How do I make it appear like the 3rd picture on final load?

Table HTML example below:

```
<table class="appDataTable projDataTable">
            <tbody>
  <tr class="appTableHeaderRow">
                <th>latitude</th>
                <th>longitude</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>animalid</th>
                <th>deleted</th>
                <th>uploaded_by</th>
                <th>date_added</th>
            </tr>
                <tr class="appTableContentRow">
                        <td>-12.293057</td>
                        <td>141.959796</td>
                        <td>2012-09-08 22:01:05</td>
                        <td>662572</td>
                        <td>FALSE</td>
                        <td>Mary</td>
                        <td>2017-08-10 17:18:40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="appTableContentRow">
                        <td>-12.29293</td>
                        <td>141.959675</td>
                        <td>2012-09-09 22:00:56</td>
                        <td>662572</td>
                        <td>FALSE</td>
                        <td>Tim</td>
                        <td>2017-08-10 17:18:40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="appTableContentRow">
                        <td>-12.292628</td>
                        <td>141.962028</td>
                        <td>2012-09-10 22:09:10</td>
                        <td>662572</td>
                        <td>FALSE</td>
                        <td>nhanak</td>
                        <td>2017-08-10 17:18:40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="appTableContentRow">
                        <td>-12.303615</td>
                        <td>141.96486</td>
                        <td>2012-09-11 22:00:35</td>
                        <td>662572</td>
                        <td>FALSE</td>
                        <td>Mike</td>
                        <td>2017-08-10 17:18:40</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

And all associated CSS for the table I've written:

```
.tableRawData {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.tableBoxProjDataWS {
    max-height: 900px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.projDataTable td {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}



.appDataTable {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.appTableHeaderRow th {
    background-color: rgba(6, 47, 55, .9);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 20px;
}

.appDataTable tr td {
    border: 3px solid white;
}
```